# How to get the sql queries when trigger was triggered, upto n levels?

Tags: sql-server, list, triggers

I want to list down the queries executed before the **'AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER'** triggered up to **n** levels. The listing will be done within the TRIGGER itself.
The **n** can be 4 or less.

Any pointer or if listing can be done by any other way will be helpful?

I have to debug the front-end and back-end if bug is there.

--Edit--

Actually a cell is being update each time as empty. I have to track it down. It happens very rarely.

--Edit--

Or say how to get the last n queries executed by the user.

--Edit--
I did as follows:

```
SELECT top(15) dest.text AS [Query]
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
          --inner join  sys.sysprocesses
          -- on sys.sysprocesses.sql_handle=deqs.sql_handle
        ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

The code after -- seems to be working where as the full code gives the all users code executed queries. I comented them because It is heavy for the server.

The connecting Question is here
[SQL cell wise trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904990/sql-cell-wise-trigger)
**(Which is the flow comes before the issue posted as ' .. triggered, upto n levels?')**

Comment: you mistaged your question MySQL, I retagged it SQL-server. You seem to have solved the problem though, have you?

Comment: Ok i'll do that. This I've solved but m really out of context now. work pressure really makes you to move on fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use extended events to get the whole TSQL call stack. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094735/create-trigger-to-log-sql-that-affected-table/3149717#3149717) for example code.