# SQL cell wise trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, cell, wise

Can a specific cell wise trigger be created?

Or is

```
IF UPDATE(COLUMN) WHERE OTHER_COLUMN LIKE 'JT'
```

the equivalent present in SQL Server 2008?

**EDIT** after getting 2nd answer---

```
IF not UPDATE(CurrentNo) --// Wanted to do like this : where series ='JT'
    return

IF not EXISTS(SELECT 'True'
              FROM Inserted i
              JOIN Deleted d ON i.Series = d.Series
              WHERE i.Series = 'JT' AND d.Series = 'JT')
    return
```

Seems ok right! Please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no way of doing this declaratively. You would need to create a general Update trigger and put logic in it to return immediately `IF NOT UPDATE (column)`

If the column of interest *was* updated then you would query the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables to allow you to process rows where your condition of interest was met.

Comment: So, basically you are saying that it is possible.

Comment: @Unreason - Kind of. It is not possible to get the trigger to fire only when a certain condition is met though.

Comment: Hi, Can I create a #hashtemp table before update and use it after update? so that the pre-Update and post-Update cell values are matched and then trigger proceeds other wise returns or exits. If any one has done it already?

Comment: @Rahul2047 You don't need to. That is what the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables are for. You can join them on your PK column(s). The `inserted` table has the new values. The `deleted` table has the original values.

Comment: @Martin Smith : I was not aware of these .. any link by where I could see the use or example of using these tables with their PK. I am getting "Invalid object name 'inserted'." error. I am not able to do sp_helptext for these. I tried google I could not find. Or I am not doing it correct way. thanks a lot Martin.

Comment: @Rahul2047, you could read the docs now that you know it is possible (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). Work out the examples, it seems you are only having syntax problems.

Comment: @Martin Smith, @Unreason: OK now I have implemented 'inserted and deleted pseudo' and on test server it works like anything. And this is so nice to optimize the trigger this way. Thanking you both. Although I was not having the syntax issues, but I noticed that the IDE of ms-sql server 2008 could not recognize some objects if those are session based or user based, like a hashtable.But I could not use the PK column. Is above edited option is ok? if not then I need to know about PK column. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Tiggers are specified on tables, not on rows, columns or cells. Inside the body of the trigger you will have access to the INSERTED and DELETED tables. You can join them together to deterimine which columns were changed during an update. The [UPDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187326%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) function which is available in SQL Server 2008 (as well as previous versions) is a shorthand method for determining whether a column has changed.