# Which stored proc(s) updating certain specific columns in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to research on why certain columns in a table were not updated. To get to root cause, I am trying to identify which stored proc(s) could be updating those specific columns in the table.

So..

How do I identify stored proc(s) that would update columns aa,bb,cc in the table123  in a given database?

There could be many stored procs updating this table. This table could have many other columns. Is it possible to identify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%put text here%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend getting a tool like [SQL Digger](http://www.sqldigger.com/) - we use this regularly at work to hunt down data in SPs, etc. for precisely the kind of problem (among many others) that you are describing.

Also Redgate has a similar product ([SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm))

Answer (score 0):

If the search through the source code comes up inconclusive you can set up a trigger on the table and then [use extended events to get the full TSQL trace of the triggering statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094735/create-trigger-to-log-sql-that-affected-table/3149717#3149717).

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate Software's [SQL Prompt 5](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) has a **Column Dependencies** feature that might be useful in this situation.  You hover over a column name in a script, and up pops a window containing a list of objects that use that column, including stored procedures.

You can download a 14-day trial for free, to see if this feature works for you.

Paul Stephenson
SQL Prompt Project Manager
Red Gate Software