# Logging SQL that caused a trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

We are trying to do a bit more logging on a database table. We have got a trigger that works on the delete of a row, and would like to record the SQL that has caused this trigger to run.

We've had a look around and cant see anything that will reliably accomplish this, has anyone ever managed to do this? we are running SQL 2008.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extended events to fire on `sqlserver.sql_statement_completed` and filtered by the `object_id` of the trigger of interest to get the whole TSQL call stack.

[See my answer here for comprehensive example code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149717/73226)