# Get the SQL query from a Trigger in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, audit

In SQL Server 2008, let's say I have a table with a view and `INSTEAD OF` triggers on it.

When I insert or update, is there a way inside the trigger to determine the SQL query that was used to invoke the trigger?

For example, if I do the following:

```
UPDATE MyView SET Address = '123 Main St'
```

Is there a way inside the trigger to get the actual SQL query that was used, i.e.,

```
UPDATE MyView SET Address = '123 Main St'
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Trigger to log SQL that affected table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094735/create-trigger-to-log-sql-that-affected-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the trigger isn't *invoked* by that statement - the triggers **is fired** from the RDBMS because the condition it's defined for (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`) has occurred.

The trigger is totally asynchronous from the actual statement, and no, you cannot get the T-SQL query that caused the trigger to fire. All you can rely on are the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables that are available inside the trigger which tell you what rows were inserted, deleted, updated.